# How to solve NLR using constraints in R for e.g. t=0,1,2,3 y=10*exp(-A* t) A>=0.001 is the constraint (Need to minimize WSS)

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, regression

I want to solve NLR using Constraint optimization(by minimizing WSS) in R followed by all summary of iteration

```
t=c(0,1,2,3,4,5)

f(t) is given below

y=10*Exp(-A*t)
```

need to fit above function by optimizing `A`.

Want to MINIMIZE WSS using Constraint `(A>=0.001)`

Help Appreciated..!!

Comment: You taged with "Windows SharePoint services". I guess you don't mean that by WSS. Can you not simply use `nls`?